# MAF sensor problem?

Tags: fuel-consumption, vauxhall, maf, zafira

i have a 2012 vauxhall Zafira 1.7cdti ecoflex motor which has low mpg, i have tested for obd2 codes but there are none,live tests show MAF sensor readings fluctuating from 7.9 to 15.11 g/S on tick over with engine at 77 degree c,850 rpm, MAP reading constant 110Kpa.
is my MAF sensor suspect? the motor drives fine,

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Further to my request for any information about MAF sensor Faults, my 2012 zafira decided to blow itself up (engine wise) and to have diesel runaway, again no faults prior to this happening were present,OBD2 error codes have not been recorded from ECM, car towed away, i await the final results...

Comment: Usually, a diesel runaway is the death knell for an engine. They usually don't come back from it. With a diesel, you don't have to have an error code present for it to do it ... it just needs a fuel source and air. A leaking turbocharger can provide the fuel (oil leak) and if there's no air shut off, it will run itself to death. Hopefully not in your case, but when you say "runaway" I think "boom".